# Google Analytics crash reports in iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics, ios8

I included Google Analytics in my project and see in reports no full log errors

```
NSInvalidArgumentException Trace: <redacted> <redacted> <redacted> <redacted> <redacted> <redacted> <redacted> <redacted> <redacted> <redacted>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

[[GAI sharedInstance] setTrackUncaughtExceptions:YES];
```

But how do I see the full log?

Comment: what the error u faced